# Kosterlitz-Thouless in the XXZ chain: instanton condensation?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-phase, spin-models, spin-chains

The anisotropic spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ Heisenberg chain $$H = \sum_n S^x_n S^x_{n+1} + S^y_n S^y_{n+1} + \Delta S^z_n S^z_{n+1}$$ is known to have the same physics as the two-dimensional classical XY model. More concretely, at $\Delta = 1$ it undergoes the (topological) Kosterlitz-Thouless transition, below which it is has algebraic decay of correlations and above which it is has exponential decay. Usually this is shown by using the quite sophisticated methods of bosonization to show that its field theory description is given by the sine-Gordon model, which is also the field theory describing the standard KT transition.

The intuitive picture behind the 2D classical KT transition is that there is an entropic gain when adding a vortex, which eventually beats its energetic cost at the KT transition, leading to a condensation of vortices. My question is then: is there a similar `intuitive' picture for the 1D quantum spin system (without having to resort to bosonized field theories etc)? In particular, can I *in the spin language* have a simple picture of something (presumably instantons) condensing at $\Delta = 1$?

Answer (score -1):

The analogue of 2D vortices for a 1D spin chain is domain walls. This is easily visualized by drawing a straight line through the centre of the 2D vortex: when we cross the wall, the spin density changes orientation until it has the opposite orientation:

[image]

A cartoon of a magnetic domain wall:

[image]